# Insert Image in PDF with jsPDF / HTML5 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jspdf

I'm trying to add an Image to a PDF-File using jsPDF-lib. The PDF is created, but the image is corrupted and looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the same Data-URL in my code like the example here: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf
My Full code attached below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
                <!-- Scripts down here -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var doc;

        function clicked()  {
            doc = new jsPDF();
            var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ***DATAURL_HERE***';
            doc.setFontSize(40);
            doc.text(35, 25, "Test-PDF");
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
            writeFile();
            alert("File was written");
            }

        function writeFile() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onError);
        }

        function onFSSuccess(fs) {
            fileSystem = fs;
            createRoot();            
        }

        function createRoot(e) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Download/", {create: true}, createFile);
        }

        function createFile(dirEntry) {
            var dir = "Test.pdf";
            dirEntry.getFile(dir, {create: true, exclusive: true}, saveFileToRoot);
        }

        function saveFileToRoot(f) {
            f.createWriter(function(writerOb) {
                writerOb.write(doc.output());
            });
        }

        function onError(e) {
        }

        </script>
    <h1>Testfile working</h1>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Clickme</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas!? Would be grateful for every help!

Comment: So... can u post link to original image?

Answer (score -1):

change ***DATAURL_HERE*** for the Canvas URL Image, you can calculate with this function:

var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!